# Unity3D iOS Enterprise Update Options

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

We develop and sell enterprise apps distributed via Apple's Enterprise developer program:  https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/

What this basically means is that we self-host and install iOS apps on our client's employee devices without going through any sort of app-store layer from Apple.  (the enterprise license lets companies self-sign and distribute arbitrary apps on non-jailbroken devices with no intervention from Apple)

With this in mind, would it be possible for us to push Unity3D incremental code-updates to our iOS users via:
http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/scriptsinassetbundles.html

(or any other method?)

Or are we still restricted to only non-code assets in iOS because of the compiler technology itself?

Answer (score 0):

That documentation seems to imply that it wont work:

> "If you want to include code in your AssetBundles that can be executed in your application it needs to be pre-compiled into an assembly and loaded using the Mono Reflection class (Note: Reflection is not available on platforms that use AOT compilation, such as iOS)"

MDM can be used to distribute (and manage app updates) on enterprise apps, without having to manually copy .ipa files around:
https://www.apple.com/support/business-education/mdm/

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Yeah, I know MDM (and the far better third party options) exist but mainly wondering if any run-time execution technical options exist on iOS when you aren't artificially constrained by AppStore approval requirements.